# Cómo puedo eliminar el directorio web en la url de mi aplicación Symfony

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, symfony3

qué tal?

Me gustaría eliminar el directorio folder en la url de mi aplicación Symfony 3.1.
He encontrado buceando por la red el siguiente .htaccess para colocarlo en la raíz de la aplicación. Se supone que debería de redireccionar hacia los ficheros app_dev.php o app.dev dependiendo del entorno en el que me encuentre.

.htaccess:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Obtengo el siguiente error en el log de apache:

```
[Mon Oct 10 22:31:50.491377 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 3860:tid 1752] [client 127.0.0.1:15119] AH01276: Cannot serve directory G:/www/animals_fever/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.pl,index.cgi,index.asp,index.shtml,index.html,index.htm,default.php,default.pl,default.cgi,default.asp,default.shtml,default.html,default.htm,home.php,home.pl,home.cgi,home.asp,home.shtml,home.html,home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Aquí está la configuración del vhost de apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "G:\www\animals_fever"
    ServerName www.animals-fever.dev
    ServerAlias animals-fever.dev
    <Directory "G:\www\animals_fever">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que no había visto bien las rutas que pones...

A ver, si has instalado la aplicación Symfony en el directorio:

G:\www\animals_fever

Deberías tener una estructura de directorios similar a:

```
G:
└── www
    └── animals_fever
        ├── app
        ├── bin
        ├── composer.json
        ├── composer.lock
        ├── README.md
        ├── src
        ├── vendor
        └── web
```

Eso sería una aplicación Sf 2.3.x; para Sf >= 3.1.x cambia un poco, y tendrías algo así:

```
G:
└── www
    └── animals_fever
        ├── app
        ├── bin
        ├── composer.json
        ├── composer.lock
        ├── README.md
        ├── src
        ├── test
        ├── var
        ├── vendor
        └── web
```

(Todo esto es configurable, pero hablo del estándar)

El punto de entrada a la aplicación web (o controlador frontal), el app.php o bien app_dev.php, estará en el directorio web; por tanto, hay que poner ese como DocumentRoot del vhost apache; así:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "G:\www\animals_fever\web"
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php app.php
    ServerName www.animals-fever.dev
    ServerAlias animals-fever.dev
    <Directory "G:\www\animals_fever\web">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Eso debería funcionarte sin problemas.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Sin probarlo, yo diría que el problema es que no tienes definido el poder sobreescribir la configuración de vhost / apache.

Es la directiva AllowOverride; en Linux Mint / Ubuntu (y Debian me parece que también), viene por defecto deshabilitada para todas las opciones:

AllowOverride None

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Prueba con:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "G:\www\animals_fever"
    ServerName www.animals-fever.dev
    ServerAlias animals-fever.dev
    <Directory "G:\www\animals_fever">
        AllowOverride Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Échale un ojo a esto:

http://symfony.es/documentacion/como-configurar-bien-apache-para-las-aplicaciones-symfony2/